# PySpark: How to transform data from string to data (or integer) in an easy-to-read manner

Tags: pyspark

I have a date column in dataframe that that looks like this:

`"JAN20, FEB20, MAR20 .... JAN21, FEB21, MAR21..."`

This created a problem when I tried to plot numbers by this timestamp, as these are technically strings (not sortable), not timestamp or integer.

I guess one way is to convert "JAN20" into "20_1" so that it first sort by year, then sort by month, but then it loses the readability / interpretability as "JAN20".

Alternatively, is there a way for me to specify that `"JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN ..."` is the right string order?

Would appreciate any input into how do I transform this column, so that it could be properly sorted, and properly show on a time series plot.

Much appreciation!

P.S This is in PySpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append an index before each of column, like this `01Jan20, 02Feb20, ... 10Oct20, ...`. Don't forget the leading zeros, you might need more than one depends on the number of columns you have.

Comment: That's a good strategy, thank you!